# How to fit the rectangle in the frame proportionally?

Tags: java, swing, paint, java-2d, jcomponent

Try to draw a rectangle with different size, How to fit it in one frame proportionally(assume the frame is fixed)?

```
public class Draw extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int width = 100;
        int length = 100;
        g.drawRect(10, 10, width, length);
    }
}

public class DrawRect { 
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.add(new Draw());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method, not the paint() method. This advice is made daily. Search the forum for more information and examples.
2. If you want to know the space available to the component then you can invoke the getWidth() and getHeight() method. Once you know these values you can determine how big you want to paint your rectangle.
3. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.
4. You don't need to use the getContentPane() method. Since JDK5 you can just add components directly to the frame and they will be added to the content pane for you.